# Direct API Calls from Visualforce Page

Tags: salesforce1-app, security-review

I am finding it pretty exciting to make webservice calls directly from visualforce + javascript. Specially with frameworks like Angular, you can directly consume JSON and render HTML templates pretty quickly. As this saves 1 extra hop to reach Salesforce servers via Remoting and then calling actual API endpoint.

Only down side to this approach is Salesforce security, which is completely bypassed, i.e.

1. No need of any remote site settings etc.
2. All calls are made from Javascript, so API Keys might be hacked. In some cases its not that critical, specially when getting geo locations etc via Google maps.

What are your thoughts on this approach ? This would surely not get thru Security review, if I am not wrong ?

Comment: Doesn't this still consume API requests? That's a big downside if that's still the case.

Comment: If we have a system and we are doing Oauth its still good I guess during security review but not sure otherwise

Comment: How do you avoid xss issues when doing a javascript call directly to the endpoint?

Comment: @KevinO'Hara no it bypasses sfdc completely, so no API requests consumed.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava we are getting api keys to various Google services, so not really oauth here.

Comment: @DanielHoechst you bought a point which I avoided for sake of simplicity in this discussion :) You're are right, its a valid possibility.

Comment: I must be missing something. Has something changed since this post? https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/06/calling-the-force-com-rest-api-from-visualforce-pages-revisited.html

Comment: @KevinO'Hara yea we have remotetk, which keeps everything on page i.e. oauth tokens/clientId etc. I hope apps using remotetk are not getting rejected in security review, can somebody confirm on that ?

Comment: Which API's are you using Salesforce REST API and Google?

Comment: I am using Google Places and Geo coding REST APIs via javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Considerations...**

I would look at this based on the correct placement of logic (aka [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)) calling the desired API in conjunction with an optimisation perspective. In the case of logic consuming **Google Places** and **Geo API**'s typical scenarios are JavaScript client side based, hence why Google provide JavaScript client side libraries.

**Browser restrictions on making API calls client side...**

There is also the fact that its not possible to make web API calls from JavaScript to a domain outside of the domain your page is served from, see [Same orgin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). If however your chosen API offers this ability through [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) or the more favourable [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) standard to permit calls to be made cross origin you can of course **choose server or client side**.

**Thoughts on remotetk...**

Note that the proxy approach used by [remotetk](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-JavaScript-REST-Toolkit), essentially makes the call via Apex code on the server on the clients behalf, will still require **Remote Site Settings** to be setup, as such I would not expect the Security Review team to necessarily fail in respect to this, though they may raise concerns about bypassing [CRUD and FLS security](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Enforcing_CRUD_and_FLS), as i don't see any checks for this in the code [here](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-JavaScript-REST-Toolkit/blob/master/RemoteTKController.cls). That said, ultimatly the **Salesforce REST API** the proxy delegates to will be enforcing this, so i suspect this might be something that can be explained to the Security Review team.

**More of a logic placement thought...**

Basically ask yourself if the logic belongs on the client or is better served from the server. Then if the user would really would benefit from skipping a server side step or not. Rich clients are becoming increasingly popular and as a result Apex controller logic in such solutions is minimal in some cases. That said if your looking for transactional containment around any database updates your making following API callouts, then your still going to want to wrap this in server side code, leveraging something like [JavaScript Remoting](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm). Finally before you get to carried away writing JavaScript code, do make sure you have a good unit testing framework in place.

**Security and Sensitive Info**

From a security perspective, I think you have mainly answered your own question in respect to expose some potentially sensitive credentials / tokens in respect to your use of such API's from JavaScript code.

**Package Installation**

My last thought would be more in respect to advertising what third party services you are using during package install. Since when you define Remote Sites adminstrators can see where data is flowing outside of Saleforce easily. Something may want to consider documenting clearly in your release notes if some callouts made client side.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew for insightful reply. So to conclude, as with remote/forcetk, if oauth tokens and client id in Javascript are fine, so should be the API keys ?

Comment: It really depends on how concerned you would be if someone got hold of them and started making API calls effectively as "your app", personally i would have said it's pretty dangerous stuff to share tbh.